# Predicting user selections based on similar user

Tags: probability, predictive-models, recommender-system

Lets say you give a set of users a set of polls, or give them a choice of foods to eat, or let them listen to a group of songs (guess like pandora).  So looking at the choices that all the users make you can match user 1 with user 5 based on the the 1st 10 choices they make.

So you taking user 1 you present him with the next poll (or whatever) and he chooses, then I can take user 5 and present him with the same choices.  I think I could then say with a certain probability that user 5 will select the same one that user 1 selected based on prior history.

What is this statistical/mathematical process called?

How would I code it in general?  (I know this isn't the right place for it, but I suppose if I know what the process is called I could find it).

Well now I see there is the tag called predictive models, but I am not sure if that is the right term and what specific form I am trying to describe?

Comment: I think this general area is called recommender systems. For example, take a look at the Netflix prize research.

Comment: Also look up "collaborative filtering".

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Why don't you make an answer ... provide an  introductory paper or book, some description and why it is suitable and you are done :).